# Unable to install LAN driver in RedHat (*** /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.el6.i686/build: No such file or directory)?

Tags: linux, rhel, drivers, make

I tried to install the Realtek LAN driver on my RHEL Server (running version 6.4).

In the folder extracted: `autorun.sh` `log.txt` `Makefile` `README` `src`

```
\>type command: ./autorun.sh     
\>output:     
    check old driver and unload it.
    build the module and install    
    make: \***  /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.el6.i686/build: No such file or directory. Stop.    
    make[1]: \*** [clean] Error 2    
    make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

But there is a file named "build" in `/lib/modules/2.6.32-358.el6.i686/`. No "build" directory though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "build" directory is actually a link to the kernel source code directory:

```
$ ls -l /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/build
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Mar 13 07:52 /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/build -> ../../../usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64
```

You need to install the kernel-devel package which "provides kernel headers and makefiles sufficient to build modules" via a command like

```
# yum install kernel-devel
```